# Java: Threads working without all classes having public void run()?

Tags: java, multithreading, dynamic, overloading

I have a relatively large amount of code written without threads in mind. I am new at Java, and programming in general, so I am having a little trouble figuring out how to run the program I have built in threads without going back into all my classes and changing them to have a run() method. I can't even imagine how that's possible where I have multiple methods that are meant to be called separately from other classes.

I can't seem to find a way to create a thread for (every/a) new call to the code from the GUI. Say I have a method for inserting data into a database. The method is named and written. I could put a call to that class and method into my main, but what then when I want to call some other method? I have 25+ methods at least, and I can't really see my main class just being overloaded 25 times as "Best practice." Is there a way to create a thread and give it an object to handle dynamically, so to say?

In short: I want to use threads in my program without overloading my main, how do I do so?

Comment: If your code was not specifically written to be thread-safe, it won't work properly on multiple threads.  Correct, performant multi-threaded development is _hard_.

Comment: It sounds like you may have to learn a bit more about multi-threaded programming. This book is a good reference on the topic (in Java): http://jcip.net/

Comment: Why do you want to run it in multiple threads?

Comment: I'd vote Bruno's answer up if I could.  This is an important, worthwhile recommendation.

Comment: I have bookmarked this page, and I will take up reading the recommended book once I have time available for it! Thank you for the link. The main reason for multiple threads is that I don't want my GUI to lock up if any of the process code for some reason hangs. I'm going to just have 2 threads, now. One for the GUI, and one for process calls.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, there is no universal way of converting singlethreaded application to multithreaded because it requires different design depending on your goal. And "multithreaded application" is not really a goal :)

You didn't specify how you built your UI. But if you use Swing and want to do some lengthy task without freezing your user interface use [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

On the general note I'd recommend reading book "[Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601)". It's pretty good.

Comment: I'll definitely have a look through that book as soon as I have time available. Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need every method / class to run in its own thread, or to implement the run method.  What you should do is that for each action a user can perform, there should be a corresponding class that implements an Action (or something similar interface).  When a user invokes an action on the UI, you should then add the action to a queue.

A separate pool of threads should then take actions from the queue and execute them (via the method exposed by the action interface).

You need to make sure that each action is thread safe and is able to run concurrently with the other actions.  This is not a simple task, and not generally something that beginners are able to do.

It may be sufficient for you to merely separate your rendering code from your processing code (so only 2 threads, users can only run one action at a time).

Comment: Separating rendering code and processing code seems like the best thing I can do at present. This is a school project and so time is limited, otherwise I'd of course have looked into doing this in a better way. In a small program (Only meant to have one user at a time anyway), I assume all I'd have to do would be put the GUI into one thread and all process code calls into another? Or, as you said, maintain a list of tasks for the process code thread and have it go through them one by one. I assume these tasks would be in the form of runnables, somehow?

Comment: As I understand it, you would normally have one thread responsible for rendering and / or input, and another thread(s) responsible for processing.  If it was me, I would encapsulate my tasks in their own interface that would then be invoked by my own thread (so a runnable) that grabbed the tasks off of a probably blocking queue (the advantage of your own interface is that it allows you to pass in data to the task, but the task could always fetch data instead).  I assume that this is a solved problem already, and frameworks must exist to do multithreaded client UI nicely.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to have all your classes have a run method or implement Runnable typically there are specific things you want to do in a separate thread, often so you dom't lock the UI while you perform a potentially slow operation like talk to a database, the file system or the network.

The simplest way is to just create a new thread when you need to do this:

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
         // do whatever work you want...
    }
};

t.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an anonymous inner class that does whatever you need. Consider something like the following. A new (unnamed) subclass of Runnable is created that performs the actual steps needed.

```
public class GuiCommandDelegator {

    void performBackgroundSave(final Document document, final String filename) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override void run() {
                document.save (filename);
            }
        };

        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.run();
    }

}
```

Certainly there are drawbacks, but it would be worse to sprinkle thread-management code all through classes that are already dedicated to specific purposes.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand where this should be placed. In my controller class, or in each class separately? I'm also a little foggy on how the whole @override thing works. Still a beginner!

Comment: You should use an `ExecutorService` to execute tasks rather than creating a new dedicated thread for every task (which is an expensive operation).

Comment: That depends on the situation. It might not be worth the added work of passing an `ExecutorService` instance around (or sprinkling references to a singleton throughout the code base). And the cost of creating a new thread is nothing compared to the implied disk (or network) activity one would expect to be associated with a method called `document.save(filename)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not have threads in your application currently, I would suggest you to look into using the Executor framework to parallelize your application. In both cases you will have to create the Runnable instances. The [JCIP](http://jcip.net/contents.html) book provides a sample chapter which should help you with this. If you do not want to end up creating 25+ Runnable inner classes, you can just create a single custom Runnable class that [uses reflection to invoke those methods for you](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang.reflect/invoke-method-using-reflection.html):

```
public ReflectiveRunnable {

  private final Object target; // needs to be non-null
  private final String methodName;
  private final Object[] argValues;
  private final Class[] argClasses;

  public ReflectiveRunnable(Object target, String methodName, Object[] args) {
    this.target = target;
    this.methodName = methodName;
    this.argValues = args;
    this.argClasses = new Class[args.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
      argClasses[i] = args[i].getClass();
    }
  }


  public void run() {
    try {
      final Class cl = target.getClass();
      final Method mthd=cl.getMethod(methodName, argClasses);
      mthd.invoke(target, argValues);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      // handle exception
      e.printStackTrace();
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks very interesting, but at present it's quite simply way above my level. I've bookmarked this page and will gradually trawl through all the answers and their tips, however. Thank you!

Comment: Anonymous inner classes are really not that verbose.  Also, using this suggestion would remove the ability of the compiler to check your the method calls and make refactoring code and introspection much more difficult.

Comment: The JIT will happen from the calling method, the only overhead will be in the use of reflection from the runnable.
In any case, using Java 8 lambdas and method references should simplify this much more.